# Compare two time in flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

I would like to compare `last_uploaded_time` with `current time`.
How to check whether the two time is more or less than one minute?

```
bool compareTime(String starts) {
    print(starts);
    var start = starts.split(":");

    DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.now();

    String currentTime =
        DateFormat(DateUtil.TIME_FORMAT).format(currentDateTime);

    print(currentTime);

    var end = currentTime.split(":");

    DateTime initDateTime = DateTime(
        currentDateTime.year, currentDateTime.month, currentDateTime.day);

    var startDate = (initDateTime.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(start[0]))))
        .add(Duration(minutes: int.parse(start[1])));
    var endDate = (initDateTime.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(end[0]))))
        .add(Duration(minutes: int.parse(end[1])));

    if (currentDateTime.isBefore(endDate) &&
        currentDateTime.isAfter(startDate)) {
      print("CURRENT datetime is between START and END datetime");
      return true;
    } else {
      print("NOT BETWEEN");
      return false;
    }
  }
```

**Output**

```
I/flutter (12908): 01:16
I/flutter (12908): 01:40
I/flutter (12908): NOT BETWEEN
```

Comment: Will this work out? https://pub.dev/packages/timeago

Answer (score 1):

```
void main() {
  String getDifference(DateTime date){
      Duration duration =  DateTime.now().difference(date); 
      String differenceInMinutes = (duration.inMinutes).toString();
      return differenceInMinutes;
  }
  String str =  getDifference(DateTime.parse('2021-09-24'));
  print (str);
}
```

i tried above code on dartpad, you can use this to compare tow dateTime variables. As per above example, you can get more options to compare for eg `duration.inDays`,`duration.inHours`,`duration.inSeconds` etc.

Answer (score 0):

> difference

not exactly working with minutes and seconds so you can use some custom algorithm like

> import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
>
> class IntelModel {   static String timeSinceDate(DateTime date) {
> final now = DateTime.now();
> final difference = now.toLocal().difference(date.toLocal());
>
> ```
> if ((now.day - date.day) >= 8) {
>   return 'A few weeks ago';
> } else if ((now.day - date.day) >= 1) {
>   return '${(now.day - date.day)} days ago';
> } else if (now.day == date.day) {
>   if (now.hour > date.hour) {
>     if ((now.hour - date.hour) >= 2) {
>       if (now.minute == date.minute) {
>         return '${(now.hour - date.hour)} hours ago';
>       } else {
>         var mins = now.minute - date.minute;
>         if (mins > 1) {
>           return '${(now.hour - date.hour)} h ${(now.minute - date.minute)} minutes ago';
>         } else {
>           return '${(now.hour - date.hour) - 1} h ${60 + mins} minutes ago';
>         }
>       }
>       
>     } else if ((now.hour - date.hour) == 1) {
>       int timeMin = now.minute + (60 - date.minute);
>
>       if (timeMin == 60) {
>         return '1 hours ago';
>       } else if (timeMin >= 60) {
>         return '1 h ${timeMin - 60}  mins ago';
>       } else {
>         return '$timeMin minutes ago';
>       }
>     }
>   } else if (now.hour == date.hour) {
>     if (now.minute > date.minute) {
>       return '${(now.minute - date.minute)} minutes ago';
>     } else if (date.minute == now.minute) {
>       return '${(now.second - date.second)} seconds ago';
>     }
>   }
> } else {
>   return 'Error in time';
> }   } }
> ```